# HttpPost releaseConnection useage

Tags: java

I have a reqeust list that have 10 requests, which are same format just one different parameter,and those requests are all post to same URI.
I am not so clear on how releaseConnection doing, and I have a code like below:

```
HttpPost testPost = new HttpPost(http://test.mysite.com:8008/);
try{
    for ( int index = 0; index < getRequests().size(); index++ ) {
        String request = getRequests().get(i);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request , Consts.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");          
        post.setEntity(se); 
        HttpResponse response = getHttpclient().execute(post);
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(); 
        Document document = reader.read(response.getEntity().getContent()); 
        //do something with the document
    }
} finally {
    post.releaseConnection();            
}
```

And I try to modify the loop to below, it still work:

```
HttpPost testPost = new HttpPost(http://test.mysite.com:8008/);

for ( int index = 0; index < getRequests().size(); index++ ) {
    try{
        String request = getRequests().get(i);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(request , Consts.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml");          
        post.setEntity(se); 
        HttpResponse response = getHttpclient().execute(post);
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(); 
        Document document = reader.read(response.getEntity().getContent()); 
        //do something with the document
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();            
    }
}
```

Which way is better to handle the connection release?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using first way because:

- In your second case, you are closing the connection with every http call
- In your second case, you are creating new connection with every call.